# display words from one ID in one line in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like so:

```
 ID | word
 ___________

 1  | hello
 1  | goodbye
 1  | goodnight
 2  | What
 2  | Why
 3  | Yes
 3  | No
```

Is there a way to collect the words with the same ID and display it in one line like so:

```
 ID | word
 _______________________________

 1  | hello, goodbye, goodnight
 2  | What, Why
 3  | Yes, No
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(word SEPARATOR ', ') word
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f04c/1)
- [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║           WORD            ║
╠════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ hello, goodbye, goodnight ║
║  2 ║ What, Why                 ║
║  3 ║ Yes, No                   ║
╚════╩═══════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

group by 'ID' and use the function [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 1):

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select ID, group_concat(word separator ', ') from yourTable group by ID;
```